# Threading model of Spring WebFlux and Reactor

Tags: java, multithreading, reactive-programming, project-reactor, spring-webflux

Currently experimenting reactive programming with **Spring 5.0.0.RC2**, **Reactor 3.1.0.M2** and **Spring Boot 2.0.0.M2**.

Wondering about the **concurrency and threading model** used by WebFlux and Reactor to properly code the application and handle the mutable state.

The Reactor doc states that the library is considered concurrency agnostic and mentions the Scheduler abstraction. The WebFlux doc does not give information.

Yet when using WebFlux through Spring Boot, a threading model is defined.

From my experimentations here is what I got:

- The model is neither 1 event thread, nor 1 event thread + workers
- Several thread pools are used
- "*reactor-http-nio-3*" threads: probably one per core, handle the incoming HTTP requests
- "*Thread-7*" threads: used by async requests to MongoDB or HTTP resources
- "*parallel-1*" threads: one per core, created by Schedulers.parallel() from Reactor, used by delay operators and such
- Shared mutable state must be synchronized by the application
- ThreadLocal (for application state, MDC logging, etc) are not request scoped, so are not very interesting

Is this correct ? What is the concurrency and threading model of WebFlux: for example what are the default thread pools?

Thank you for the information

Comment: "concurrency and threading model of WebFlux and Reactor" depends on your app code. Neither Spring WebFlux not Reactor forces a concurrency model on you. You'll want to look into concurrent reactive programming.

Comment: You're actually asking for the "threading model" of Spring, Reactor, Netty, your reactive database drive, etc. There's no way one can answer that correctly.

Comment: @BrianClozel can you point some places in docs about default configuration of threading in spring-webflux? Are "event-loop" threads spinned up like vertx based on cpu core's by default?

Comment: @BrianClozel I am so confused as well. In our application we see elastic-2, elastic-evictor-1, parallel-1, reactor-http-nio-1, reactor-http-nio-2, reactor-http-nio-3 ... till reactor-http-nio-40 : Thread count : 40 threads of this type. This Spring Boot 2.0.0.RC1 runs on Alpine Docker image. The same app has 4 reactor-http-nio threads on my 4 core laptop. So confusing what these mean and no where in the document there is proper mention of any of these. So sad to see such a neglect from Spring team.

Comment: There is substantial documentation for Spring WebFlux https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#spring-webflux. Rather than calling that effort neglect, please help to improve it by identifying what's missing, see for example https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16538.

Comment: @RossenStoyanchev It still doesn't explain the bug we are seeing. Using Alpine Linux distro and using Spring Webflux the reactor threads are going till 40 threads. The same app if used with other linux distros like centos or windows laptop is using the default of  2 * Available cores .

Answer (score 56, accepted):

After the question, the [present documentation does provide some clues about the concurrency model](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-concurrency-model) and the threads one could expect (but I still think that clearer/better descriptions of what happens under-the-scene from a multi-threading perspective would be highly appreciated by Spring newcomers).

It discusses the difference between Spring MVC and Spring WebFlux (1-thread-per-request model vs. event-loop):

> In Spring MVC, and servlet applications in general, it is assumed that applications may block the current thread, e.g. for remote calls, and for this reason servlet containers use a large thread pool, to absorb potential blocking during request handling.
>
> In Spring WebFlux, and non-blocking servers in general, it is assumed that applications will not block, and therefore non-blocking servers use a small, fixed-size thread pool (event loop workers) to handle requests.
>   Invoking a Blocking API

But notice that Spring MVC apps can also introduce some asynchronicity (cf., Servlet 3 Async). And I suggest [this presentation](https://www.infoq.com/articles/Servlet-and-Reactive-Stacks-Spring-Framework-5) for a discussion wrt Servlet 3.1 NIO and WebFlux.

Back to the docs: it also suggests that, when working with reactive streams, you have some control:

> *What if you do need to use a blocking library?*
>
> Both Reactor and RxJava provide the publishOn operator to continue
>   processing on a different thread.

(For more details on this, refer to [scheduling in Reactor](http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#schedulers))

It also discusses the threads you may expect in WebFlux applications (**bold** is mine):

> *Threading Model*
>
> What threads should you expect to see on a server running with Spring WebFlux?
>
> - On a "vanilla" Spring WebFlux server (e.g. no data access, nor other optional dependencies), you can expect **one thread for the server, and several others for request processing (typically as many as the number of CPU cores)**. Servlet containers, however, may start with more threads (e.g. 10 on Tomcat), in support of both servlet, blocking I/O and servlet 3.1, non-blocking I/O usage.
> - The reactive **WebClient** operates in **event loop style**. So you’ll see a **small, fixed number of processing threads related to that, e.g. "reactor-http-nio-" with the Reactor Netty connector**. However if Reactor Netty is used for both client and server, the two will share event loop resources by default.
> - Reactor and RxJava provide thread pool abstractions, called **Schedulers**, to use with the **publishOn operator that is used to switch processing to a different thread pool**. The **schedulers have names that suggest a specific concurrency strategy**, e.g. **"parallel" for CPU-bound work** with a limited number of threads, or **"elastic" for I/O-bound work** with a large number of threads. If you see such threads it means some code is using a specific thread pool Scheduler strategy.
> - **Data access libraries and other 3rd party dependencies may also create and use threads of their own**.

In part, you can configure the details of the threading model via configuration

> To configure the threading model for a server, you’ll need to use server-specific config APIs, or if using Spring Boot, check the Spring Boot configuration options for each server. The WebClient can be configured directly. For all other libraries, refer to their respective documentation.

Moreover, as e.g. the discussion  [Default number of threads in Spring boot 2.0 reactive webflux configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46925508/default-number-of-threads-in-spring-boot-2-0-reactive-webflux-configuration) 
highlights,

> The default number of threads for request handling is determined by the underlying web server; by default, Spring Boot 2.0 is using Reactor Netty, which is using Netty's defaults

it is a matter of default components and their defaults (and overall configuration, including that injected transparently through annotations)  -- which may also change across versions of Spring/Boot and corresponding dependencies. 
Said that, your guesses seem correct.

Comment: if my reactive endpoint needs to call an external, non-reactive endpoint which does blocking stuff, is my reactive endpoint still reactive? I use reactive WebClient to call this external non reactive endpoint

Comment: @user1955934 if you are using a SDK provided by that 3rd party, needs to be reactive as well. If you are just calling another endpoint, it doesn't matter because your own computer is freeing threads from being blocked by whatever that response lasts