# Default number of threads in Spring boot 2.0 reactive webflux configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, reactive, spring-webflux

While using Spring 5 reactive webflux with Spring boot 2.0, what's the default number of threads used to handle requests? How can I configure the number of threads used?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The default number of threads for request handling is determined by the underlying web server; by default, Spring Boot 2.0 is using Reactor Netty, which is using  Netty's defaults (check out the `EventLoopGroup` documentation for that).

Spring Boot will soon allow you to customize that part (see [#10418](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/10418)). In the meantime, you can provide your own `ReactiveWebServerFactory` bean and change that through the `HttpServer` configuration options (see [this comment](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/10418#issue-260209863)).

Comment: Currently I see `reactor-http-nio-1` in the logs, I use SpringBoot 2.0.0 M6. How can I configure netty to use all cores?

Answer (score 8):

Currently, it seems that Spring Webflux 2.0 does not provide the ability to control threads.

Spring Webflux 2.0 is using Reactor-Netty. And `ReactorNetty`class provides some configurations.

- reactor.netty.ioWorkerCount
- reactor.netty.ioSelectCount
- reactor.netty.pool.maxConnections
- etc

So, You can use it like this.

```
System.setProperty("reactor.netty.ioWorkerCount", "100");
```

I hope that Spring Boot will provide a custom configuration.