# Java Spring Webflux on Kubernetes: always [or-http-epoll-1], [or-http-epoll-2], [or-http-epoll-3], [or-http-epoll-4] despite configured resource

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-webflux

Small question regarding a Java 11 Spring Webflux 2.6.6+ web app, containerized and deployed using Kubernetes please.

From the web app application logs, I am seeing things such as:

```
INFO [service,1bcce5941c742568,22c0ab2133c63a77] 11 --- [or-http-epoll-2] a.b.c.SomeClass  : Some message from the reactive pipeline.
INFO [service,67cb40974712b3f4,15285d01bce9dfd5] 11 --- [or-http-epoll-4] a.b.c.SomeClass  : Some message from the reactive pipeline.
INFO [service,5011dc5e09de30b7,f58687695bda20f2] 11 --- [or-http-epoll-3] a.b.c.SomeClass  : Some message from the reactive pipeline.
INFO [service,8046bdde07b13261,5c30a56a4a603f4d] 11 --- [or-http-epoll-1] a.b.c.SomeClass  : Some message from the reactive pipeline.
```

And always, I can only see `[or-http-epoll-1] [or-http-epoll-2] [or-http-epoll-3] [or-http-epoll-4]` which I think stands for: `[reactor-http-epoll-N]`

The problem is, no matter how much CPU I allocate from Kubernetes, it is always those 4, no less, no more.

I tried:

```
  resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 1
              memory: 1G
            limits:
              cpu: 2
              memory: 2G

  resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 4
              memory: 4G
            limits:
              cpu: 6
              memory: 6G

  resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 10
              memory: 10G
            limits:
              cpu: 10
              memory: 10G
```

But again, always only those 4.

I am having a hard time understanding what is the problem here, and why am I stuck with only/always 4 "or-http-epoll-".

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WebFlux - Reactor Http Epoll threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63675128/webflux-reactor-http-epoll-threads)

Comment: I had a chance to look at the link. Especially the answer: "The number of default threads is dependent on the core count of the host system." This is why I am asking my question. I do configured different variation of number of core count, but still seeing the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default WebFlux uses Netty as an underlining web server. Here is how Netty determine number of threads in the pool [Netty - LoopResources](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/blob/main/reactor-netty-core/src/main/java/reactor/netty/resources/LoopResources.java#L41)

```
/**
* Default worker thread count, fallback to available processor
* (but with a minimum value of 4)
*/
int DEFAULT_IO_WORKER_COUNT = Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty(
    ReactorNetty.IO_WORKER_COUNT,
    "" + Math.max(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors(), 4)));
```

The next question, what is the current `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()`?

It depends on Java version. Until Java version 10, application on Docker sees CPU on the machine and not inside the container.

You could create a simple Java application to validate

```
class TestCpu {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       int processors = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
       System.out.println("CPU cores: " + processors);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is indeed the correct answer. For some reason, this piece of code always shows the same number no mater how many CPU I allocate from Kubernetes side. I believe it is more of a Kubernetes issue rather than a Spring issue. Thanks you

Comment: what java version are you using for containers?

Comment: I am using a regular alpine java 11 as base image, and as for Kubernetes, using AKS